# c# multithreaded dictionary - refresh live dictionary with new set of values best practices. Create new Dict, or reload old dict item by item?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary, thread-safety

I have a Dictionary of complex objects that needs to be updated whenever the database with its source data changes. Entries might have changed, been added, or removed, so essentially we need to recreate/reload the entire Dictionary. As far as I can tell, there are a few different ways to do this, I was wondering if there was a best practice? (or if my understanding of the comparison is correct)

Lock statements, clearing and adding item by item

```
    lock (myLock){
            myDict.Clear();
            foreach (var itemToAdd in itemsToAdd)
                myDict.Add(config.key, config);
        }
```

Item by item adding to the dictionary, and then removing anything that shouldn't be there

```
var tmpDict = LoadDictionary();
foreach(var key in myDict.Keys.ToList()) //check for deleted keys
    if(!tmpDict.ContainsKey(key))
          myDict.TryRemove(key, out _);
foreach(var pair in tmpDict) //update or add every key
    myDict[pair.Key] = pair.Value;
```

Doing a straight swap (incorporating comment from the General)

```
public ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> myDict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();;
public void UpdateDictionary(){
     Interlocked.Exchange(ref myDict, LoadDictionary());
}
```

As far as I can tell, the last option should work fine so long as you never store a reference to the dictionary elsewhere (as you won't get any updates to your ref'd dictionary). The first one will stop any access until the dict is updated (being safer if out of date values are a concern, and should be fine for smaller dicts), and the second option avoids locking the object and avoids losing references, but runs you at risk of accessing old values for a few milliseconds/seconds after receiving the update prompt

This is a fairly poorly formatted question (sorry), but is there a best practice/standard for performing the above operation? And/or are there any major holes in the above code snippets?

edit: In my use case, we have several independent services running, and the database will be changed by one of them, so we can't update the dictionary first, but being a bit out of date isn't a huge deal either.

Edit2: misunderstood what interlocked.exchange did, still improves my solution though

Comment: Do you care if (who ever is accessing the dictionary) has the chance of stale values when the data changes?

Comment: If you don't care about the chance of reading a stale value, just replace the reference or use `Interlocked.Exchange(ref _dict, newDictionary);`

Comment: You have not disclosed crucial information related to how database data changes. is it via same app? Can you first update the In-memory dictionary and then fire-off a task to update DB. We can only arrive at a suiting solution, when flows, tolerances and fallbacks etc have been identified.

Comment: May I ask why you are doing these? If this dictionary is to keep some sort of audit functionality and you are using entity framework you can override OnSaveChanges()

Comment: In my specific use case it's to redirect queues based on the database config, but I'm also just interested in the general case for future problems

Comment: *"the second option [...] runs you at risk of accessing old values"* <== IMHO the first solution has the same problem too. You are locking the dictionary *after* having fetched the `itemsToAdd`, so during this fetching the dictionary is accessible and contains old values. And fetching data from the database should be more time-consuming than updating an in-memory collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With option 1, note that you have to lock not only on write, but on all reads, otherwise lock is useless. That means reads will block each other, and if going this route - at least user `ReaderWriterLockSlim` instead of simple lock.

Option 2 leaves dictionary in inconsistent state (some values are old, some are new) for a brief moment, which also might be a concern, plus `ConcurrentDictionary` should have some overhead over regular dictionary (most of the times it's irrelevant, but who knows your specific use case).

Option 3 should be the fastest. Note that I believe there is no need to use `Interlocked.Exchange`, you can just assign:

```
myDict = LoadDictionary();
```

But also note that to ensure other threads are not reading some cached value - it makes sense to mark `myDict` with `volatile` (which has some quirks, but in your specific use case should work fine).

Then, there is no need to use `ConcurrentDictionary` in option 3, because you are never writing to that dictionary (after it's assigned and available to readers that is). So better make it something like `ReadOnlyDictionary`. Reading from multiple threads is safe as long as that dictionary is never modified.

Comment: I like the answer, i might add though `Interlocked.Exchange` is not just about atomicity, its about memory visibility +1, all though references are atomic, they can still be cached, which the op may or may not care about

Comment: Yes but that we hopefully covered by making field volatile.

Comment: ahh yup. i see where you are going

Answer (score 1):

This answer deals with the case of large dictionaries that are subject to few and infrequent changes, and there is some mechanism in place that fetches only the differences from the database (based on timestamps or something). Under these conditions, you could consider using an [`ImmutableDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutabledictionary-2) instead of a normal dictionary (or a concurrent one). It has the disadvantage of being slower and having a larger memory footprint compared to the mutable dictionaries, with its advantage being its capability of providing very cheap snapshots of the data. This is possible because it is essentialy a snapshot by itself, since it is immutable. On the contrary creating snapshots of mutable collections is only possible by creating copies of the whole collections, which can cause contention because the collection is locked during the copy operation.

```
private ImmutableDictionary<string, string> _myDict
    = ImmutableDictionary.Create<string, string>();

public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> MyDict
    => Volatile.Read(ref _myDict);

public void UpdateDictionary()
{
    ImmutableInterlocked.Update(ref _myDict, current =>
    {
        // The method below should fetch the changes from the database
        KeyValuePair<string, string>[] changes = GetChangesFromDB();

        var builder = current.ToBuilder();
        foreach (var change in changes)
        {
            if (change.Value == null)
                builder.Remove(change.Key); // Remove
            else
                builder[change.Key] = change.Value; // Add or update
        }
        return builder.ToImmutable();
    });
}
```

The methods of the `ImmutableDictionary` class (`Remove`, `SetItem` etc) do not modify the instance. Instead they return a new instance. This is affordable because they are implemented internally as binary trees, consisting of mostly reusable nodes. For more than a handful of modifications it is more efficient to use a [builder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutabledictionary-2.builder), as in the example above.

The [`ImmutableInterlocked.Update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutableinterlocked.update) is a built-in helper method for updating atomically any type of reference-type variables, not only immutable collections:

> Mutates a value in-place with optimistic locking transaction semantics via a specified transformation function. The transformation is retried as many times as necessary to win the optimistic locking race.